# To instance variable or not... problems with dealloc

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ivar

So in my ARC project, whenever I assign my ViewController using an instance variable, it appears dealloc is never called when dismissing or popping the controller.

In my header:

```
ComposerView *composeView;
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ComposerView *composeView;
```

...

```
@synthesize composeView;
```

then in my code:

```
if (composeView == nil)
      composeView = [[ComposeView alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: composeView];
```

Now, inside composeView, I have set all delegates to nil, but dealloc is never called and subsequently, viewDidLoad isn't called again when reloading the view controller.

If I don't use instance variables, and I just create it directly, everything is fine. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC then you should be declaring your properties as strong/weak instead of retain/assign.

You probably want

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) ComposerView *composeView;
```

Check this link out for a description of strong/weak:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226